# Getting Mysql Database changes and downloading files

Tags: java, mysql, polling

For a project I need to list any mysql database changes in a java program. De database contains links to files.
The purpose is whenever a link in de database changes the java program gets notified and starts downloading the file.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I think the simplest way is to use a MySQL trigger to save any updated links in a special table and poll that with your Java application instead of the data table itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use database trigger which will populate a new table (let say it named link_change) each time there is update or insert operation onto the link table.

This link_change then will need to be polled periodically (E.g.: using select, via JDBC), and being processed by your java program. And it should delete the records that has been processed.

Ref:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html